# How to modify field value in other nodes after node update?

Tags: 8, nodes, hooks

After node update I need to modify a field value in several connected nodes.
As I know, I cannot use `hook_entity_update()` since `$node->save()` forms infinite recursion.

How can I modify node fields after a node has been updated? (besides `hook_cron`)

Comment: You get an infinite recursion only if you do the node saves in the update hook unconditionally.

Comment: I need to modify a field value in another node in `hook_entity_update()`. Could you provide a tip what condition can help to stop infinite recursion?

Comment: hook_node_upate already implies the check for the entity type. If you reference a different content type add a check for the content type. If you reference within the same content type then the calculation of the field values could already imply a check,  otherwise the recursion is somehow built into your logic. Then it could make sense to refactor the updates to a service which would keep track of the updated nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.5.x) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.4.x)

Add a custom validation that runs after all validation has passed

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_update_referenced_nodes';
```

Then in that function

```
function mymodule_update_referenced_nodes(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state){

  $field_other = $form_state->getValue('field_other')[0]['value'];

  $references = $node->get('field_referenced')->referencedEntities();
 
  foreach ($references as $referenced_node) {
    $referenced_node->field_other->value = $field_other;
    $referenced_node->save();
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I could have guessed myself. Not universal solution (only for form update). But acceptable for the case.

Comment: @nosssweat, I am wondering why you use validation instead of another submit handler. Don't you have a risk of inconsistencies if saving of the node fails?

Comment: @Neograph734 actually you're correct, should be put in a submit instead, thanks.

Comment: @Dimetry updated answer.

Comment: @NoSssweat Oke. I was just wondering if doing it in validation had some advantage or something, as I always used submit. Apparently it does not ;)